# highcharts example for using data from database with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Does anyone have a simple example of populating a Highchart with data from a MS SQL DB using DotNet.Highcarts?

I have the demo working with static data

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
        .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
        .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
        .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Membership Overview" })
        .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Paid Members", "Active Members", "Retained Members", "New Members", "Lapsed Members" } })
        .SetYAxis(new YAxis
        {
            Min = 0,
            Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Total Members" }
        })
        .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +''; }" })
        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions { Bar = new PlotOptionsBar { Stacking = Stackings.Normal } })
        .SetSeries(new[]
                   {
                       new Series { Name = "Total", Data = new Data(new object[] { 441, 441, 22, 30, 610 }) }
                    });
```

How can I change the Series to accept data from my DB?

Assuming I need to connect to DB like so:

```
var newcustomer = db.Customer;
```

Then do something like this:

```
new Series
{
    Name = "Total",
    Data = new Data(newcustomer.Select(x => ............
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else having a similar issue...

```
var paidmembers = (from c in db.Customer
                   where c.CustomerStatusID == 1
                   select c).Count();

var activemembers = (from c in db.Customer
                     where c.CustomerStatusID == 2
                     select c).Count();

new Series {
            Name = "Category",
            Data = new Data(new object[] {paidmembers, activemembers})
}
```